# Verifying Marketing Cloud API calls

Tags: trigger, api, logging, marketing-cloud

So I'm new to the Dev. Forums, and trying to learn as much as I can while studying for my MC admin and developer certs, so forgive me if this question isn't clear.

In Marketing Cloud we have a lot of triggered communications that are sent via API calls from different source systems. Is there a way to see all the source systems and API calls that send to Marketing Cloud?

Comment: these is not an api console to show you incoming api calls, you could possible use the audit log for ip address/user that are authenticating

Comment: We've found it helpful to consolidate API calls through a single service rather than multiple plugs in to SFMC. This makes it easier to manage but would require an additional service layer.

Comment: @EazyE How would one implement an audit log? Could you do it directly within Marketing Cloud?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_audit_trail.htm&type=5